# Prove that a sequence is Cauchy in $L^1$ norm

Tags: integration, cauchy-sequences

The question I had in mind in particular was to find a sequence of integrable simple functions that is Cauchy but does not converge for the $L^1$ norm to a simple function- in particular I found a sequence of functions:

$$\bigg\{\frac{1}{n}\lfloor nx \rfloor\bigg\},$$

but I had a lot of difficulty showing that it was Cauchy. I ended up making some kind of hand-wavy argument that allowed me to drop off the absolute value signs in the norm at the expense of adding on a term to the difference. What is the preferred way to go about a proof like this? The triangle inequality doesn't(I don't think) yield a small enough number for each difference in the sequence.

Comment: Cauchy sequence in which norm?

Comment: The $L^1$ norm?

Comment: $L^1$ is complete, so every Cauchy sequence must converges.

Comment: I'm sorry, the function I'm dealing with are the integrable simple functions- ones that can be written as $\displaystyle \sum^n\chi_jb_j$, for finite $n$, and where $\chi_j$ is the indicator function of some set $E_j$. I want the $L^1$ norm, but not on the space of all functions.

Comment: @Anthony: Then you should edit your question to clarify this!

Comment: Also: Is that function $\frac{1}{n} [nx]$? (where $[\cdot ]$ stands for the integral part)? Is your space $L^1([0,1])$?

Comment: Oof- yeah I was using floor which is the same as the integral part, right? And I suppose we can take the space to just be that. If not, we can just say it's zero outside $[0,1]$, right? Sorry for the lack-of-detail.

Comment: @Anthony: So I suppose you can show that your sequence converges  in $L^1([0,1])$ to $f(x) = x$?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can, I was starting with trying to show that it was Cauchy- I was hoping the proof would illuminate the way I should be working with the absolute value in the norm.

Comment: I think it will be easier to show that it converges to $f(x) = x$. If that can be done, your sequence is automatically Cauchy

Comment: Oh, I suppose so. I suppose that calculation would be fine- I did want to see the calculation to show that the sequence was Cauchy though....

Comment: Okay, I don't have a clear picture now, but I think you can do the following: for each $n$, $m$. Divide $[0,1]$ in $mn$ subintervals and see what would happen for $|\frac 1n [nx] - \frac{1}{m} [mx]|$ in each intervals.

Comment: Oh that may have been what I was doing- I said that we can drop the absolute value signs if we add on enough to make up for the parts that can be negative. Thanks for your input!